# Unknown coordinate system from web API

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, wgs84

I'm trying to figure out (and eventually convert to WGS) projection system of coordinates I get from one web API service. As an example - **lat, long = 71804125, 180232666** is a point in Cracow, Poland. 
Any ideas what it can be?

Comment: Can't be lat/long, units are not in degrees eg. lat would expect values +/- 0 to 90 and long +/- 0 to 180

Comment: What's the web service? Do they have any documentation?

Comment: It's not epsg:3857 or epsg:32634 (utm). rbkb is right--you should find your answer in the API documentation.

Comment: Ok, I've solved it. Checked website source and it turned out that it's just WGS multiplied by 3600000. No idea why anyone would do something like this.

Comment: The lon/lat angles here seem to have been expressed in milliarcseconds. Hence a division by 3,600,000 converts them back to degrees.

Comment: That's interesting, haven't met that before.